# How to limit the number of users who can connect to an Windows-based access point using netsh?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, netsh

I have a Wi-Fi dongle with the RTL8188EUS chipset. I'm using it to make a access point from a computer that has Windows 7. However, I have noticed that the dongle shuts off when 12 or more people are connected to it and I have to restart the *hostednetwork*.

When I do

> netsh wlan show hostednetwork

it shows that the maximum amount of clients is 100.

```
Mode                   : Allowed
SSID name              : "name"
Max number of clients  : 100
Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
Cipher                 : CCMP
```

Is there any way to reduce this number with the *netsh* command, does it require some additional work?

Thanks for answering.

Comment: If the host runs DHCP, give it only 10 IP addresses to hand out, and set aggressive scavenging options.